# Create specific table in LaTeX

Tags: latex, tabular

I am trying to code the table below in LaTeX but I could not make it align.  I am hopeing  you can help.

[image]

Comment: Can you add some code clarifying _"but I could not make it align"_? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if it's useful to confront your own code with the following sketch (please compile it):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll}
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Table 7}\\
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text text text text text text text text text}\\
  \midrule%\toprule
  ... & ...\\
  Step 2: & \multicolumn{1}{p{.85\textwidth}}{%
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text%
    \begin{enumerate}[a.]\item first\item second\end{enumerate}}\\
  ... & ...\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```